# Safe way to terminate an endlessly looping goroutine?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine, waitgroup

I have a goroutine that is acting as a listener. A stream of input is coming in on a certain buffered `channel`, and I want my goroutine to process data as it comes in on that channel. However, there may come a time where no data comes in on that `channel` for awhile. If the `channel` has nothing to offer for one second, I want my goroutine to do something different. The function looks like this:

```
func main () {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    arr := make([]*myObject, 0)
    wg.Add(1)
    go listener(c, arr, &wg)
    for {
        // sending stuff to c
    }
}

func listener(c chan *myObject, arr []*myObject, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        select {
        case value := <- c:
            arr = append(arr, value)
        case <- time.After(1 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println(arr)
        }
}
```

The problem is that I want to see everything that went through the channel printed out. If `main` finishes suddenly, there might be some stuff left in `arr` that hasn't been printed out yet, and I won't see it. So I need to make sure that this goroutine is finished processing all the data in the channel before the program finishes. That means, I think, that I need to use a `WaitGroup` and use `Wait()` to ensure that the program doesn't close before my goroutine is done doing what it needs to do. **But I can't figure out where to call `Done()` on my `WaitGroup`.**

Basically, I need a safe way to "pause" the goroutine at the end, before the program finishes, and print out whatever is left. How can I do that?

Even worse, for things like unit tests, I send the data to the channel myself, and after I've sent a certain amount, I want to see the array. But if I just check the array immediately after the code to send the data to the channel, the goroutine may not have had a chance to process all the data yet. In that case, I want to wait for the goroutine to process all the data I've sent, and then I want to pause it and ask it to show me the array. But how do I know when the goroutine is finished processing? I could `sleep` for awhile and give it a chance to finish, and then stop it and have a look, but that feels rather hackish. I'm thinking there's a best-practice way to handle this, but I'm not figuring it out.

Here are some ideas I had, zero of which work.

1. Call `Done()` outside of the infinite `for` loop. This doesn't work, because that code, as far as I know, is unreachable.
2. Call `Done()` in the timeout `case`. This doesn't work, because there may be more data on the way after a timeout, which I want my goroutine to keep listening for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the listener to return when the channel is closed. Call wg.Done() on return:

```
func listener(c chan *myObject, arr []*myObject, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case value, ok := <- c:
            if !ok { return }
            arr = append(arr, value)
        case <- time.After(1 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println(arr)
        }
}
```

Modify the main to close the channel when done sending.  Wait for the goroutine to complete before returning from main.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
arr := make([]*myObject, 0)
wg.Add(1)
go listener(c, arr, &wg)
for {
    // sending stuff to c
}
close(c)
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your goroutine will terminate after 1 second, whether or not there is more data in the channel. If you want it to terminate after 1 second of waiting, you have to change the logic a bit:

```
func listener(c chan *myObject, arr []*myObject, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    tmr:=time.NewTimer(1*time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case value, ok := <- c:
            if !ok {
               return
            }
            arr = append(arr, value)
            // Reset the timer. First, you need to stop it
            if !tmr.Stop() {
                <-t.C
            }
            // Now reset it
            tmr.Reset(1 * time.Second)

        case <- tmr.C:
            fmt.Println(arr)
        }
}
```

Then, you have to close the channel after you're done sending to it:

```
for {
    // sending stuff to c
}
close(c)
wg.Wait()
```